# Docusign API, document content not showing

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to use a **sandbox demo Docusign api v2.1** to create an envelope, everything works great except the actual content in the document does not show in the signing view.

I've tried various PDF files as well as Word files. Also verified that my base64 encoding of the binary file is valid.

Here is my code for the document section of the envelope definition:

```
"documents": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "docusign test document",
      "fileExtension": "pdf",
      "documentBase64": "#base64FileContent#"
    }
  ],
```

Appreciate if anyone experienced this before could give me some pointer.

Answer (score 1):

here is the full enevlope definition code i am sending for the enevlope creation:
{ "documents": [ { "documentId": "1", "name": "docusign test document", "fileExtension": "pdf", "documentBase64": "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" } ], "emailSubject": "test agreement for signature", "status": "sent", "recipients": { "signers": [ { "recipientId": "1", "clientUserId": "1000", "email": "russell@test.com", "name": "Russell Liu", "routingOrder": "1", "tabs": { "signHereTabs": [{ "xPosition": "100", "yPosition": "100", "documentId": "1", "pageNumber": "1" }], "initialHereTabs": [{ "xPosition": "200", "yPosition": "100", "documentId": "1", "pageNumber": "1" }] } } ] }, "eventNotification": { "includeDocumentFields": "false", "envelopeEvents": [ { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Completed" }, { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Declined" }, { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Voided" } ], "url": "https://sap.wegbox.com/docuback", "requireAcknowledgment": "true", "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField": "false", "loggingEnabled": "false", "includeDocuments": "false", "signMessageWithX509Cert": "false" } }

Answer (score 0):

Can't help much without full code, but I can make a suggestion.
Try to use text file, add just like 1-2 characters. Make it as simple as possible and see if you can see anything. That would be a good way to isolate where your issues is.

can you try this:

```
"documents": [
    {
      "name": "Lease",
      "fileExtension": "PDF",
      "documentId": "101",
      "documentBase64": "IyMgRGRzCgoKQ...0KCgoKCg==."
    },
    {
      "name": "Pet addendum",
      "fileExtension": "PDF",
      "documentId": "231",
      "documentBase64": "IyMgVGFicwoKKipU...WJzLgoK"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: i tried using simple text file, still the same behavior.

Comment: modified my answer to add an example from https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/documents
can you try that?

Answer (score 0):

Your PDF is blank - you'll need to look into how you are generating the PDF or converting it to base64.

To confirm this:

- take the base64, paste it in to a tool like Notepad++
- decode the base64 bytes in to binary
- save as file.pdf
- open the PDF file in a PDF viewer.